# How to pick the enabled tag from HTML code (Selenium)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

In below attached image, I'm trying to pick the enabled tag. But i couldn't.
Is there any way to pick all the attribute values of only enabled tag.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWPLK.png)

```
 <div class="site-status" data-connection="true" data-configuration="true">
    <img id="site-status-error" aria-label="Not Connected" aria-describedby="site-status-error" role="alert" alt="Connected" src="img/icn_error.svg" style="display: none; background-color: transparent;">
    <img id="site-status-ok" hidden="" aria-label="Connected" aria-describedby="site-status-ok" alt="Not Connected" src="img/icn_check.svg" style="display: inline;">
    </div>
```

First **img** tag is disabled. Second **img**  tag is enabled.

Comment: Can you please copy your HTML code here instead of image so we can examine it properly .. it will help us to help you better

Comment: @Shubham Jain : I have pasted html code above. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below xpath:-

```
//div[@class='site-status']/img[not(@style='display: none;')]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you. I got the logic right of considering 'not'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not working if you use id for enabled tag   as it is unique{//img[@id='site-status-ok']} ideally it should work??

Can you please provide the code which you are using to click on this image.

Answer (score -1):

Try this xpath for

```
//*[@class='site-status']/img[2]
```